# Chrome Extension Passing Variable to dynamically executing scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a chrome extension which opens a jquery Dialog and ask user about the current website.

here is what i have done so far

**background.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var tabUrl='';
            chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
                tabUrl=tab.url; //this varible i want to pass to popup.js

                chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, 
                {file:"jquery-ui.css", 
                    runAt:"document_start"}, 
                function() {  });
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, 
                {file:"jquery.js", 
                    runAt:"document_start"}, 
                function () {

                    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, 
                    {file:"jquery-ui.min.js"}, 
                    function () {
                        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file:"popup.js"}, function()       { 
                        });                    
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
        <script ></script>
    </head>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
$(function() {
var myurl='http://localhost/addReview.php?url='+tabUrl;
var NewDialog = $('<div id="MenuDialog" ><iframe id="loader" frameborder="0" style="height:400px;width:100%" src="'+myurl+'"></iframe></div>');
NewDialog.dialog({
        modal: true,
        title: "Curate to WishCart",
        show: 'clip',
        hide: 'clip',
        width: '744'
});

});
```

I tried with the other way i copied my popup.js code to background.html but then extension console showing following errors.

1. undefined symbol $
2. Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dialog'

I want to pass the tabUrl to to popup.js so i can load the i-frame and send current tab url with iframe src attribute.

Comment: did you include jQuery (and jQueryUI) in your code? I can't see it anywhere.

Comment: You can add jQuery and jQueryUI including the CSS as normal <script> and <link> tags to your background.html. No need to .executeScript

Comment: Perhaps this approach will help you better: http://blog.michael-forster.de/2009/08/using-jquery-to-build-google-chrome.html

Comment: yes dialog gets opened properly so it means my jquery.js and jqueryUi is loading ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Script, that is passed to the `chrome.tabs.executeScript` method will be executed as a [Content Script](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html). It means, that it will not have any access to the context of the background page and variables defined in it.

I'm not sure, but accordingly to the documentation, you can try to use the following approach:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, 
    {
        file: "popup.js", 
        code:"showDialog(" + tabUrl + ")"
    });
```

Note: accordingly to the example above, the `showDialog` function must be defined in the **popup.js** file as a global function.